# How to iterate over Instance attributes name and value in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have this class

```
class Person
attr_accessor :id, :name

  def initialize(id, name)
    @id   = id
    @name = name
  end

  def print_attr
    self.attributes do |attr_name, attr_value|
      print "attribute name: #{attr_name}, attribute value: #{attr_value}"
    end   
  end
end
```

print_attr is currently wrong. How can I implement it?

Answer (score 3):

`attributes` is rails specific.

You need to iterate through `instance_variables` and then use `instance_variable_get`

```
def print_attr
    instance_variables.each do |attr_name|
        attr_value = instance_variable_get(attr_name)
        puts "attribute name: #{attr_name}, attribute value: #{attr_value}"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using as Struct to define your class if your class has many of these simple attributes. It will take care of the boring accesors and initialize method, leaving the clever stuff to you:

```
 Person =  Struct.new(:id, :name) do
  
  def print_attr
    self.each_pair do |attr_name, attr_value|
      puts "attribute name: #{attr_name}, attribute value: #{attr_value}"
    end   
  end

end

a = Person.new(123, "Joe")

a.print_attr # => attribute name: id, attribute value: 123
             # => attribute name: name, attribute value: Joe
p a.class    # => Person
```